No internet connection while using vless config with q2ray and v2rayX
I am using a vless config. I try to set it up using v2rayX and qv2ray. When I click on latency test it returns a ping. This is the log I get on qv2ray when turning the proxy on:
Xray 1.8.23 (Xray, Penetrates Everything.) 4c82ef8 (go1.22.5 linux/amd64)
A unified platform for anti-censorship.
2024/08/03 23:32:45 [Info] infra/conf/serial: Reading config: /home/benyamin/.config/qv2ray/generated/config.gen.json
2024/08/03 23:32:45 [Warning] core: Xray 1.8.23 started
2024/08/03 23:32:45 127.0.0.1:43448 accepted tcp:127.0.0.1:0 [QV2RAY_API_INBOUND -> QV2RAY_API]
2024/08/03 23:32:47 127.0.0.1:36484 accepted //ssl.gstatic.com:443 [http_IN >> twfkylcywdxrqdd]
2024/08/03 23:32:49 127.0.0.1:36492 accepted //askubuntu.com:443 [http_IN >> twfkylcywdxrqdd] 

but I lose my connection to internet all of a sudden: there is something wrong with the proxy server, or the address is incorrect.
I use the same config on my other devices. I followed this tutorial for ubuntu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7rcs1uN8uU
